# Getting Error in Powershell script while invoking exe file

Tags: powershell

I want to invoke an exe file from a drive having a variable drive name.
The code first searches the path in every drive of the system and once found it enters the If condition where I want to invoke a command -bpimagelist.

Below is the code which gives an unusual error.

```
for($pat=67 ;$pat -le 87 ;$pat++)
{
 $y = [char]$pat;
$path = $y+":\Veritas\Netbackup\bin\admincmd"
If((Test-Path $path))
{
Write-Host $path "is found in" $y "drive"
Invoke-Item $y":\Veritas\Netbackup\bin\admincmd\bpimagelist -client abc.ge.com -d 11/01/2014 -U"
break
}
Else
{
continue
}
}
```

ERROR :

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\abala\Desktop> .\veritasscript.ps1
D:\Veritas\Netbackup\bin\admincmd is found in D drive
Invoke-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Veritas\Netbackup\bin\admincmd\bpimagelist -
client hclinnobpm01.jnj.com -d 11\01\2014 -U' because it does not exist.
At C:\Documents and Settings\admin_broy5\Desktop\veritasscript.ps1:8 char:17
+      Invoke-Item  <<<< $y":\Veritas\Netbackup\bin\admincmd\bpimagelist -clien
t hclinnobpm01.jnj.com -d 11/01/2014 -U"
```

=================================================

I'm not sure why the Error shows C:\Veritas when the current value of $y is D and also in the Write-Host line it prints as path found in D drive.
Can someone please suggest a method to invoke an exe file above?

Comment: Yes it does exists in D drive, that is why the first line of the output is - "D:\Veritas\Netbackup\bin\admincmd is found in D drive"

Comment: No sir, even including bpimagelist in TestPath doesnt works.
For test purpose currently I'm trying to invoke fsutil.exe located at C:\Windows\syste32 with below code but even this doesnt works.
     Invoke-Expression "volume diskfree "$y":"
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong cmdlet when you use `Invoke-Item`

Change it to `Invoke-Expression` or `iex`:

```powershell
Invoke-Expression "$($y):\Veritas\Netbackup\bin\admincmd\bpimagelist -client abc.ge.com -d 11/01/2014 -U"
```

Comment: Even this doesn't works. 
For a simple test I'm trying to invoke windows fsutil file:
 Invoke-Expression "fsutil volume diskfree "$y":"
But even this doesnt works. Error below:
Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:'.

Comment: Be __VERY__ careful with that command because of the colon. It should be: `Invoke-Expression "fsutil volume diskfree $($y):"`

Comment: In fact, I get the same error when I try the command you pasted, so you have it wrong. I would test with the full command in your question before you can be sure it won't work

Comment: THanks Arco444, this indeed works with NO error. So what the catch I figured out is , In case a variable comes inside Invoke-Expression, we need to use $ twice to make shell understand that its a variable. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, spot on. And I'd even missed that in my own answer..! Have updated to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, this was a test of invoking exe files which I was doing from home.But My requirement is to invoke bpimagelist in Prod environment in office which has switches like -d, -U in the expression. So will this affect the result or do we need to modify our code. Your reply will be tried tomorrow in Production environment.Thanks in advance

Comment: This finally works in Prod env also.
Thanks arco444 , thanks everyone else.
For readers, moral of the story is - Use double pound sign in case you want to use a variable inside Invoke-Expression.
@Arco -Any else you want to add? 
I'm closing the thread from my end.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be to use `Start-Process` instead of one of the Invoke commands.

Here is an example:

```
Start-Process "$y:\Veritas\Netbackup\bin\admincmd\bpimagelist" -argumentList @("-client abc.ge.com","-d 11/01/2014","-U")
```

If this throws the same error you should check the machine if bpimagelist really exists.

For more info on running executables with powershell check out the [Technet Wiki](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

Comment: I'll try Start-Process tomorrow when I reach office in Prod environment. Meanwhile at home, I'm trying to invoke simple fsutil.exe with a variable drive name inside Invoke-Expression which now works with the helpful reply of arco444. But this is not my requirement. I want to invoke bpimagelist which has few switches in the expression which I'm not sure will work or not.I'll try tomorrow and post here. THanks